# Drawing a cloud of points

Tags: python, python-2.x, matplotlib

I decided that it would be nice to write some code to draw a cloud of points.

Of course my first thought was to draw some random points but the result is not cloud-ish, it is well... random.

In the end I decided to use the **Mitchell** random points algoritmh generating pretty good results:

- Blue = Random
- Red = Cloud (Michelin)

[image: Example plotting]

```
from __future__ import division
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

# The more the nearest the points
RANDOM_POINTS_PER_GENERATION = 6

def random_point():
    return [random.random(), random.random()]

def average(lst):
    return sum(lst) / len(lst)

def distance(a,b):
    return ((a[0]-b[0])**2 + (a[1]-b[1])**2)

def nearest(random_points, seen_points):
    def distance_to_points(point):    
        return average([distance(point, seen_point)
                             for seen_point in seen_points])
    return min(random_points, key=distance_to_points)

def next_point(points):
    random_points = [random_point() for _ in range(RANDOM_POINTS_PER_GENERATION)]
    return nearest(random_points, points)

def mitchell(number_of_points):
    """
    Generates almost random points, but at each iteration
    `k` points are generated and the nearest is taken, in
    order to have a better looking points-cloud.
    """
    points = [random_point()]
    while len(points) < number_of_points:
        points.append(next_point(points))
    return points

def plot_points(points, color):
    plt.plot(*zip(*points), color=color, linestyle='none', marker='.',
             markerfacecolor='blue', markersize=4)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    plot_points(mitchell(250), "red")
    plot_points([random_point() for _ in range(250)], "blue")
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `mitchell` is the only function with a docstring. What do all the other functions do? How do I call them? What do they return?
2. A function's name should describe what it does, or what it returns, rather than the name of algorithm it uses (which is typically an implementation detail). So I would use a name like `point_cloud` instead of `mitchell`.
3. Your implementation picks the random sample that is *closest* to *all* the other points, but the algorithm described in Mitchell's 1991 paper "[Spectrally optimal sampling for distribution ray tracing](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.95.7523&rep=rep1&type=pdf)" picks the random sample that is *furthest away* from *any* other point (see section 4, "Sequential Poisson-Disk Sampling"). This is so different that I think it would be better not to use the name "Mitchell" to describe the algorithm.
4. It would make the code easier to use if `RANDOM_POINTS_PER_GENERATION` were a keyword argument to `mitchell`, rather than a global variable. Consider a program that tries to determine a good value for this parameter, or a program with two pieces of code that need different values for the parameter.
5. `mitchell(0)` returns a list of one point, but surely this should return a list of no points?
6. Instead of:

   ```
   while len(points) < number_of_points:
   ```

   write:

   ```
   for _ in range(number_of_points - 1):
   ```

   since you know that each iteration adds exactly one point.
7. The function `average` is built into Python under the name [`statistics.mean`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean).
8. The function `distance` is misleadly named: it actually calculates the *squared distance* between points. Similarly, `distance_to_points` returns the mean square distance to the points.
9. The function `nearest` doesn't need to take the `average`: since `seen_point` has the same length in every case, the `sum` of the squared distances would be just as good.
10. Instead of creating a temporary list that gets thrown away immediately:

    ```
    average([distance(point, seen_point) for seen_point in seen_points])
    ```

    use a generator expression:

    ```
    sum(distance(point, seen_point) for seen_point in seen_points)
    ```
11. At each stage `nearest` finds the average squared distance from a candidate point to each point in the cloud, making the overall runtime \$ O(kn^2) \$. However, it's possible to do better than that. For each candidate point \$ q \$, the value that needs to be computed is the sum of squared distances, $$ \sum_j \left|p_j - q\right|^2. $$ Using the [dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) we can expand the square, getting $$ \sum_j (p_j - q)·(p_j - q). $$ Multiplying out, we get $$ \sum_j p_j·p_j - 2q·\sum_j p_j + q.q \sum_j 1. $$ Since we taking the *minimum* of this value over all the candidate points \$ q \$, we don't need the first term \$ \sum_j p_j·p_j \$ as this is the same for all \$ q \$ and so cannot affect the result.

    What this means is that if we keep a running sum \$ \sum_j p_j \$ then we can find the candidate point with the minimum sum of squared distances to all the points in the cloud in \$ O(k) \$, bringing the runtime down to \$ O(kn) \$.

    To implement this, we need a representation of vectors that supports sums and dot products. Here I'm using NumPy arrays:

    ```
    import numpy as np

    def point_cloud(n, k=6):
        """Generate a point cloud with n points. At each step k (default 6)
        candidate points are generated and the one whose sum of squared
        distances to the other points is smallest is used.

        """
        if n == 0: return
        p = np.random.random(size=2)
        yield p
        sum_p = p.copy()
        for i in range(1, n):
            # Generate k candidate points.
            q = np.random.random(size=(k, 2))

            # Sum of squared distances from each candidate point to all
            # the points generated so far, less the sum of squares of the
            # points generated so far (as this doesn't affect the minimum,
            # we don't need it here).
            s = i * (q * q).sum(axis=1) - 2 * (q * sum_p).sum(axis=1)

            # Pick the candidate that's closest to the points generated so
            # far.
            p = q[np.argmin(s)]
            yield p
            sum_p += p
    ```